# Omission of “from now”

Tags: time

Why do we not use *from now* when it is required?

For example if I say:

> I will come after 20 minutes.

instead of

> I will come after 20 minutes **from now**.

*After 20 minutes* may refer to any 20 minutes, e.g., after 20 minutes of my dinner.

Then why is *from now* not required to specify the difference?

Comment: You typically wouldn't say "I will come after 20 minutes." You would probably use "I will come **in** 20 minutes."

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., we would use ***in*** rather than ***after***:

> I will come ***in*** 20 minutes
>
> OR
>
> I'll be there **in** 20 minutes.

It is idiomatic to omit the ***from now***, as it is understood or implied.

Comment: there is any rule that says that we calculate from the time  of speaking?because if we say I will come on Saturday means this Saturday it is implied if we calculate from the time of speaking but if we are not calculating that way then it may refer to any Saturday not necessarily this Saturday

Comment: @Nikita Yes, it is understood that it means from the time of speaking. In the case of Saturday, it means the next Saturday, not the Saturday after that or any other Saturday.